# VSCode how to import css snippets into less/sass/postcss

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

So, I have a `css.json` with couple of *css* snippets and `sass.json` with some *sass* snippets. Is there any way to use both *css* and *sass* snippets when I'm working on with *sass* files? Maybe use some kind of import, or set filetype of the file something like `.css.sass` (like in vim)?

Answer (score 0):

at right bottom click on `sass` and then select `configure file association for scss` and then select `css`,

[image]

-

[image]

then you can use css snippets in your sass file

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. In this case _sass_ snippets become unavailable. So you can use only css snippets.

Comment: yeah, then import that snippets be only choice .. not sure